# XMLHttpRequest из jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем сделал так

```
$.ajax({
xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        //Download progress
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                progressElem.html(Math.round(percentComplete * 100) + "%");
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
});
```

Начальник пишет что нужно как то из jquery вытащить XMLHttpRequest
Не понравилось var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

> I believe this breaks browser compatibility,

Comment: `I believe this breaks browser compatibility,` - какую версию IE вы поддерживаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 xhr: function () {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhr.upload) {
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {}
```

Comment: Спасибо только что нашел такое решение тут https://coderwall.com/p/gi-f2g/accessing-the-xhr-object-in-jquery-s-ajax Надеюсь прокатит =)